# How to add scrollbar in my nested panel and add delete button?

Tags: python, scripting, panel, tools

So i have created this custom panel (thanks to people from this community who helps me out tho )which shows list of objects based on the category i have selected from the dropdown ,i want the list in a separate box should i do it using nested panel or UILayout , also rather than it just being a list of objects I want to be able to select the objects from the list and a delete button in the bottom which will help me delete the selected object from the list.

[image]

Comment: It's not possible

Comment: @Karan any alternate approach to get a similar result ?